# Is there a block structure on the U matrix of the SVD of a block matrix?

Tags: matrices, svd

Consider a matrix $A_{m_a\times d}=U_a D_a V_a^T $ and $ B_{m_b\times d}=U_b D_b V_b^T $ with 
$$AB=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
A &|&  0 \\ \hline
0 &|&  B
\end{array}\right]
$$
Now when you do the $AB=UDV^T$, does the $U$ matrix have a block structure as well. What I see when I compute this for example with a random $A_{m_a\times2}$ and $B_{m_b\times2}$, the $U$ matrix has $U_a$ and $U_b$ contained within it but the $U$ matrix is not in a block diagonal form.For example 
$$AB=\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
U_a &|& |  \\ \hline
| &U_b& | 
\end{array}\right]
$$
 So is there a predictable structure on $U$?

Comment: If the matrix as a block diagonal structure you can certainly use the SVDs of the blocks to construct a block diagonal $U,V$. It doesn't mean that any SVD will have that structure, just that one exists.

Comment: so you mean there is no known mathematical theorem that guarantees a predictable form of U based on the U matrices of A and B. Thanks for answering btw this is my first question ever.

Comment: Well, if you have SVDs for $A,B$, you can create an SVD for the block matrix in a straightforward way.

Comment: @copper.hat, Could you show how?

Comment: Actually, I am a little confused here, you have $A,B$ on the left and right hand sides. Are you dealing with a block diagonal matrix or not?